# Ionic Studio - TypeError: Cannot read property ‘major’ of null

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-appflow

I am trying to open an Ionic project in Ionic Studio in an NX mono repo.

Unlike in the photo gallery demo project, we are using Angular 9 with Ionic 5.

When I try to open the project up in Ionic Studio using the root directory for the app (not the entire mono repo) I am getting the below error:

[[image: [1]]

My file and directory structure is identical to the Ionic photo gallery demo app and the project runs successfully in my browser when running the command $ Ionic serve.

You can see my directory structure below:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to fix this, or approach fixing this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ionic Studio IDE support team just reached out and said that Ionic Studio currently does not currently support Ionic version 5 yet.

They said it will be at least a few weeks before Ionic Studio will support Ionic V5.